# Python 3 creating multiple DF in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create multiple DFs from multiple CSV files.  In this case I have 3 CSV files and I want to loop through each and create a new DF for each file. Each file name is appended with a number 1 - 3. And I want each DF to be appended with a corresponding 1 - 3.  This will vary in future.

I created a dictionary with the DF names I want, but when I try to create the DFs from the files my code ends up loading the DF's into the dictionary instead of the creating separated DFs for me.

This is what I tried:

```
district =  'districtname'

if (district == 'districtname'):
    # setup df names in a dictionary
    dfs = {} # create a dictionary
    i = 1
    while i <= 3:  
        dfs[i] = "dfdistrictname" + str(i)
        i = i + 1
    print(dfs)   
    
    # create the DFs
    n = 1
    while n <= 3:
        filename = 'oppdetail_oppview_' + year + '_' + district + str(n) + '.csv'
        print(filename)
        print(dfs[n])
        dfs[n] = pd.read_csv(filename)
        n = n + 1
```

All the output is what I expect it's just that the line:

```
dfs[n] = pd.read_csv(filename).
```

is creating the DF in inside of the dictionary structure rather a separate DF object.

```
{1: 'dfdistrictname1', 2: 'dfdistrictname2', 3: 'dfdistrictname3'}
oppdetail_oppview_2023_districtname1.csv
dfdistrictname1
oppdetail_oppview_2023_districtname2.csv
dfdistrictname2
oppdetail_oppview_2023_districtname3.csv
dfdistrictname3
```

I know python is going it exactly what I am asking it to do.  My question is how do I get individual DFs?

Comment: Would you mind adding a sample of your desired structure? Do you want to have a dictionary with both the string `"dfdistrictname" + str(i)` AND the `dataframe`?

Comment: I don't want the data frames store in the dictionary.  I want them as separate DFs.  The only reason I used the dictionary was as a means to create and store the names I want to give the new dataframes that get created in the second while loop.

Comment: But you have to assign and store your dataframes... _somewhere_ . Do you want them injected as global variables somewhere? (and yes, you **can** do that, although I'm not that certain you *should*) If so with what names. And up to "where" do you want them to be visible? Just within your function? Visible to other functions? ...

Comment: I want my DFs to be assigned the names in the dictionary. i.e. dfdistrictname1, dfdistrictname2 and dfdistrictname3.  But I want to be able to have a loop where they get created, because there may me 10's of them and I don't want to have write a line of code for each df. i.e. dfdistrictname1 = pd.read.... , dfdistrictname2 = pd.read....  etc.  Everything is within a single Jupyter notebook, if that answers your question regarding global variables.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem right (which... I might not)

You have an unknown number of `.csv` files that you want to load globally into individual dataframes.

I suggest the following:

1. First, scan for .csv files matching your name structure (starting with `oppdetail_oppview_`, containing `district` in the name and ending with `.csv`)  using [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob).

   The example below goes look for the files in the script's working directory (`.`). This might be different in your system.
2. Iterate over the results using [enumerate](https://pythonbasics.org/enumerate/) so you get both the index in the iterable results and the `Path` object itself
3. Use the index to calculate a suitable name for the variable that will store each dataframe.
4. Load the dataframe and inject it into the [globals()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-globals-function/) symbols so they become sort of global variables.

   This last part is usually considered a not-so-good practice, since you will be basically declaring a global variable programmatically, which means all your linters will get confused. Well... and humans reading the code will get confused too. Imagine someone reading your code and all the sudden seeing the variable `dfdistrictname1` being used. Now they try to see where that variable was declared/initialized/younameit... and they won't find it.

   Also, after injecting the names in the `globals()` it would be hard to know whether you have 2 or 5 or 10 `dfdistrictnameX` variables declared.

With those ingredients, you can try the following:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

for i, path in enumerate(Path('.').glob('oppdetail_oppview_*district*.csv')):
    print(f"Found .csv in: {path}")
    name = f"dfdistrictname{i + 1}"
    print(f"Gonna name it: {name}")
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    globals()[name] = df  # Inject in the global variables

print(f"Printing dataframe dfdistrictname1:\n {dfdistrictname1}")
```